# Правильное использование предлогов: ЗА или ПОД?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно: "выдать **за** подпись в журнале" или "выдать **под** подпись в журнале"?

Answer (score 4):

В толковом словаре:

[выдать](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), **св.**
**1.** *кого-что.* Дать, предоставить, передать в чьё-либо распоряжение в соответствии с установленным порядком.  ***Выдать под расписку деньги.***

[ПОД](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%94&all=x), ***предлог***
**10.** Указывает на то, что служит порукой, ручательством чего-либо. ***Выдать под расписку.*** Отпустить под честное слово. Выдать редкую книгу под залог.

Правильно: *выдать* (документ, книгу, дело, экземпляр) ***под*** подпись в журнале.

**Дополнение**

Из [**словаря трудностей**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_37) русского языка:
Как правильно писать в документах: *под подпись* или *под роспись*?
Правильно: ознакомить сотрудников с инструкцией **под подпись** или под расписку.

[Вопрос № 254437](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C&start=15) (грамота.ру)

Как правильно (допустимо): выдать документ (и т. п.) под расписку, под роспись? Последний вариант почти повсеместно сейчас применяется!

**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Верны варианты: под подпись, под расписку.

Answer (score 1):

Предлог "**за**" здесь не подходит - получился бы смысл "обмена" одного на другое: будто в компенсацию за то, то человек расписался (ср. "товар за деньги"), ему что-то выдают. Человек ставит свою подпись в подтверждение того, что ему это выдали - расписывается в графе какого-нибудь журнала или листа учёта. Тем не менее, выражение "**под подпись**" звучит небезупречно и не всеми источниками принимается, - в отличие от вполне нормального выражения "**под расписку**".

Откуда же возникла рекомендация "под подпись"? От не вполне обоснованного противопоставления слов "подпись" и "роспись" (иногда трактуется как разг. вариант "подписи"). В юридической же практике эти слова сосуществуют как термины разного значения (см. подборку статей из Трудового кодекса): https://zakon.ru/blog/2019/4/15/rospis_i_podpis_pyatnichnoe

*Подписываются* **под документом**, подтверждая согласие с его текстом, а **расписываются** *в подтверждение **факта*** чего-либо, например, *ознакомления* с документом (= "под роспись"). В обоих случаях "подпись" - это то, что остаётся на бумаге. А "роспись" в юридическом контексте - *действие* глагола "расписаться" (такое отглагольное значение фиксируется напр. словарём Ефремовой http://endic.ru/efremova/Rospis-95041.html ).

В чём разница выражений "**под расписку**" и "**под роспись**"? В быту их не различают, но в строгом (юридическом) понимании **расписка** - *содержательный* документ, под которым ставят подпись. В ней могут быть сформулированы обязательства и т. п. Если что-то выдают "под расписку", то обычно с обязательством напр. вернуть в срок, зачастую в обмен на этот документ. "Под роспись" означает, что человеку *предложено расписаться* в учётной графе для  удостоверения факта (здесь) получения выдаваемого (напр. второй раз ему это не дадут). Поэтому в вашем случае больше подходит "**под роспись**", хотя и "под расписку" не будет ошибкой.

Comment: Простите, опять придерусь к формулировке.  *От не вполне обоснованного противопоставления слов "подпись" и "роспись"... В юридической практике эти слова сосуществуют как термины разного значения (см. подборку статей из Трудового кодекса):* Если значения разные, то это как раз и есть основание для (обоснованного!!!) противопоставления, не?

Comment: Я имел в виду противопоставление в языковых источниках - они в других ответах цитировались. Попробую частицу "же" добавить к своему противопоставлению.

Comment: А что это изменит?! Ладно, не смею настаивать... Хотя похоже, мы по-разному понимаем слово "противопоставление".